¿Como resolver el problema de servidor para en enviar correo por PHPMailer?
Estoy realizando pruebas de funcionamiento con la pasarela de PayPal, pero quiero mandar correo al cliente de detalles de su compra una vez ejecutado su pago, lo estoy haciendo con PHPMailer 6.9.1 siguiendo sus instrucciones y configuraciones correspondientes pero al momento de hacer las pruebas me sale que hay falla con servidor ya que asigne correos de gmail y también de hostinger pero igual tengo es mismo detalle.
SMTP ERROR

2024-08-16 14:00:59 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server
Error al enviar correo electronico se la compra: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server

Configuración con PHPMailer
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require '../phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '../phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'juaritoz82@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password   = '*******';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $mail->Port       = 465;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('juaritoz82@gmail.com', 'Tienda AD');
    $mail->addAddress('angeldesign082@gmail.com', 'Joe User');



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Detalles de su compra';
    $cuerpo = '<h4>Gracias por su compra</h4>';
    $cuerpo .= '<p> El ID de su compra es <b>' . $id_transaccion . '</b></p>';
    $mail->Body    = utf8_decode($cuerpo);
    $mail->AltBody = 'Le enviamos los detalles de su compra.';

    $mail->setLanguage('es', '../phpmailer/languaje/phpmailer.lang-es.php');

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar correo electronico se la compra: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}



Prueba usando el puerto es 587 y ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS

Y lo intente también me salio el siguiente error: 2024-08-16 14:55:44
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server
Error al enviar correo electronico se la compra: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to serverSMTP server error: Failed to connect to server SMTP code: 10060 Additional SMTP info: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.

Tu servidor de php tiene soporte de ssl? Podrías verificar en tu php.ini si extension=php_openssl.dll está activada o comentada.

@javdromero ya lo verifique y si esta activa.

¿Lo estás intentando desde local o desde un servidor web? ¿Tu certificado SSL está al día?

Para verificar la validez puedes ejecutar este comando desde la terminal: curl --insecure -vvI https://tudominio.com 2>&1 | grep -e "start date:" -e "expire date:" cambiando tudominio.com por el nombre real del dominio donde está alojado tu sitio. En la salida tendrás un valor para start date y otro para expire date que indicarán la fecha de inicio y de fin de la validez de tu certificado. El valor de expire date debe ser una fecha a futuro como es lógico y el valor de start date una fecha pasada. O lo puedes ver haciendo clic en el candadito en la barra de navegador.

Lo estoy intentado desde local con xampp

A mi nunca me falla la siguiente configuración

    //Server settings
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    // Pass dado por Google especial para esta App
    $mail->Password = '*ocst$$#$&hglfwmllrgvn';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;


[edit]
El Password es una contraseña generado por Google, especial para esa Aplicación, así le llama Google a un Password generado para algo en específico en su API de Desarrolladores...
Espero ayude en algo @Marcos 

@Marcos y para que?????????? Es ese el tema en cuestión?? Ese es mi comentario pero el user ya tiene su propio pass dado por Google para esa App. Dudo que no sepas a que pass se refiere eso... Si estas usando PHPMailer es obvio que sabes de que pass se trata...

Puedo apostar a que mas de uno no sabe que no debe usar el mismo password que utiliza para acceder a su cuenta de Gmail.

@Marcos pero ese no es el punto del post. De ser así porque no le preguntas al OP porque su Password son asteriscos?? El error no es el Password, el error (según creo) es de configuración del SMTPSecure y mi comentario (el pass) es algo irrelevante para este post... Entiendo tu ponto, pero es desviar un tema en algo por lo que NO han pedido ayuda. Igual ya lo hice...

A ver, puede que efectivamente no sea el caso, pero en rigor de verdad ¿en que se diferencia tu configuración de la del OP? Para mi, lo único que puede ser es esto que para algunos es obvio, que el password debe ser "especial"

@Marcos no ve que yo uso ssl?? Esa es mi propuesta, que use ssl en lugar de lo que ha usado hasta ahora.

Es que ENCRYPTION_SMTPS es igual a ssl. Mira acá

Buen punto, esperemos a ver si mi respuesta ayuda en algo o no. Por el momento lo dejamos hasta acá y luego ya vemos...

Estaba viendo sus comentarios, se ha ingresado la contraseña de aplicaciones de google, todo lo que menciona antes de publicar mi pregunta ya lo realizado y el correo no se envía.

Gracias por sus comentarios, ya lo solucione este detalle tantas vueltas que le di, el problema era con mi servidor local Xampp no se porque el  SMTP no funciona, lo que hice es subir mis archivos de prueba al webhosting y de esa manera es como ya se pueden enviar los correos.

Raro porque XAMPP trae todo abierto. Me alegra que solventaras

En mi caso yo tengo esta configuración:
//Server Settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'email@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = 'contraseña';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587

Te dejo como configurar TLS en la opción de tu cuenta de gmail
